# summing count result in two group

Tags: mongodb

My collection's data are something like this :

```
[
  {
    ANumberAreaCode: "+98",
    BNumberAreaCode: "+1",
    AccountingTime: 1629754886,
    Length: 123
  },
  {
    ANumberAreaCode: "+44",
    BNumberAreaCode: "+98",
    AccountingTime: 1629754786,
    Length: 123
  },
  {
    ANumberAreaCode: "+98",
    BNumberAreaCode: "+96",
    AccountingTime: 1629754886,
    Length: 998
  }
]
```

I'm going to group on countries codes and count result (summing country codes in ANumberAreaCode and BNumberAreaCode  ) .

This is my group sample :

```
{ "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "ANumberAreaCode": "$ANumberAreaCode",
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
```

```
{ "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "BNumberAreaCode": "$BNumberAreaCode",
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
```

now , how can i summing count result of two above queries for common countries ?

I'm looking for a query that give me this result :

```
+98 : 3
+44 : 1
+1 :1
+96 :1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this aggregation pipeline:

- `$facet` to get both group, by `A` and `B`. This creates two objects: `groupA` and `groupB`.
- Then using `$concatArrays` into `$project` stage it will concat two ouputs.
- Deconstructs the array using `$unwind`
- And `$group` again by values using `$sum` to get the total.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "groupA": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$ANumberAreaCode",
            "total": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "groupB": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$BNumberAreaCode",
            "total": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$groupA",
          "$groupB"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$result"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$result._id",
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$result.total"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B-LSZumF6Ua)